# Local outlier factor (LOF) software / demo?

Tags: statistics, outliers

Is there any software that enables me to perform LOF outlier detection towards a 2D dataset? I just implemented LOF from the original paper and want to check whether my results are correct. So far I couldn't find any tool or online service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [rapidminer](http://rapid-i.com/content/view/181/190/) application. And add [anomaly detection plugin](http://rapidupdate.de:8180/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_anomalydetection).

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the Wikipedia article on Local Outlier Factor? It mentions [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/), which has a LOF implementation (with index support, so `O(n log n)` for large data sets).

Note that many people overlook the reachability-distance in LOF, and only approximate it. The ELKI implementation supposedly is correct, so it can help you well for testing your results.

Answer (score 0):

Rapid Miner considers the IP address attribute of DARPA 1998 dataset as polynomial type data ! But LOF is not optimized for that. Interestingly RAPID MINER cannot handle such huge network traffic datasets. Any other implementation available ?